# Unique constraint violation found

Tags: database, error, magento2.3, sql, unique-constraint

when edition the product for the backend, I faced the unique constraint violation found in the Magento-2.3 . I have checked the exception log this shows

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '404-0-4-1.0000-0' for key 'UNQ_E8AB433B9ACB00343ABB312AD2FAB087', query was: INSERT INTO `catalog_product_entity_tier_price` (`entity_id`, `all_groups`, `customer_group_id`, `qty`, `value`, `percentage_value`, `website_id`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

Comment: Set Price Scope to Website (Stores -> Configuration -> Catalog -> Catalog -> Prices)-> Set the Price Scope website to Global.

Comment: It solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

This "Unique constraint violation found" bcase same value store in a unique field in data base such as if order number is not same value so if u put same value in order number than it's give "Unique constraint violation found" error.